# Array not displaying elements in template with *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ngfor

I've been collecting sample information for a CRUD app, and even though I've gotten my reports to be stored in firebase and be logged in the console, I'm having trouble with displaying those reports in my template.

I'm following this tutorial as a guide: https://www.positronx.io/build-ionic-firebase-crud-app-with-angular/

This is how I'm currently populating the array of reports:
**home_page.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchReports();
    let reportingRes = this.reportService.getReportList();
    reportingRes.snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
      this.Reports = [];
      res.forEach(item => {
        let r = item.payload.toJSON();
        r['$key'] = item.key;
        this.Reports.push(r as Report);
      })
    })
  }
```

```
fetchReports() {
    this.reportService.getReportList().valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

Fetching the reports to see if they exist, then copying them into my array.

But my template is currently not rendering anything.

**home_page.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let report of Reports" class="user-list">
      <ion-label>
        <h5>
          <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> {{report.title}}
        </h5>
        <p>
          <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon> {{report.message}}
        </p>
      </ion-label>

      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        <button ion-button clear >
          <ion-icon name="create" style="zoom:2.0"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button clear (click)="deleteReport(report.$key)">
          <ion-icon name="trash" style="zoom:2.0"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
```

[image: Report titles in console]

I tried verifying that the reports are being collected through the console log, and inside of the call to subscribe to changes on reportingRef in the ngOnInit() function in my typescript file I can see reports but as "[object Object]" instead of the data I put in. How can I properly get the data from my database and display it in my template?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, if you wrap your `<ion-item>` in an `<ng-container *ngIf="Reports">`, then you'll know if you actually have `Reports` to iterate over.

Comment: I don't get any errors in the console, just a warning that *ngIf isn't a property of ng-container, ion-item, or div so it can't bind to any of them. I checked, and Common Module is in my home_page component module's imports

Comment: @Muirik I've really hit a wall here and I'm not sure how to figure this out. Could you point me to any docs that might be of help?

Comment: So I'd say the first thing you'd want to do is check if you have data, and that that data is an array. So do you have data if you do `console.log(this.Reports);` ?. And, if so, do you know that is an array: `console.log(Array.isArray(this.Reports));`?

Comment: Also, you could hardcode a simple array in your component (that has the properties you need on each element), and then see if you can iterate over that in your view. That way you can determine if the issue is with your data or your view.

Comment: Yes, I've been able to access the data from my home page component. I added the console log above. I tried using a sample array as well and I still get the same error about 'ngForOf' even though I'm still not using it. Could this be something wrong with my template then? @Muirik

Comment: Also, looking at your error there, try doing the `*ngFor` on an ` <ion-list>` that wraps your ion-items.

Comment: Also, to see if the problem is in your template, strip it back to the simplest implementation, and see if you see data on the screen: something like: `<ion-list *ngFor="let report of Reports"><ion-item><h3>{{report.title}}</h3></ion-item></ion-list>`

Comment: Okay I tried that as well and I'm getting the same error. How do I find what the problem may be with my template? @Muirik

Comment: I would suggest you set up some sample code on a stackblitz, so we can play with it and narrow down the possibilities. Hard to do more without seeing it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic-4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I set up a sample [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fire-sample), I hope this helps @Muirik

Comment: Cool. But to clarify, what I'm suggesting is that you now copy an implementation of your app code onto this stackblitz so it can be troubleshooted in real time. As before you can hardcode a sample array and then use your same view code.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarification. The stackblitz has an implementation of my code, retrieving firebase data and there's a hard coded array in tab1. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Great. And can you provide the link to the HTML view that mirrors the `home_page.html` in the stackblitz?

Comment: Sure, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fire-sample) should lead you to see the mock home page, with the home_page component being in the tab1 folder - tab1.page.html @Muirik

Comment: All I see is a default ion-app setup?
 `<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>`

Comment: I see that markup in the app.component.html but the tab1.page.html shows something different. Is ```<ion-app>...<ion-app>``` in the tab1.page.html on your end? @Muirik

Comment: Okay, are you seeing this error in the console? `</ion-item>
"): ng:///Tab1PageModule/Tab1Page.html@20:8
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
{{report.title}}
</ion-item>` I'd try resolving that first. Check what it's telling you here about the module.

Comment: @Muirik I'm confused. Is this not the same type of error from before with *ngFor not being a property of ion-item, div, or ng-container?

Comment: I see your point. Question for you: how did you initiate this project? I think that may be where the problem lies. Did you use the Ionic CLI to start a new ionic/angular project, or did you handle it some other way?

Comment: @Muirik I used the ionic cli

Comment: That's weird. Then the error is not particuarly helpful here. I set this up using the same kind of *ngFor, with no problems:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wvvcgm. Look at the home.ts component.

Comment: Actually, maybe the error is helpful. Look at the different between the app.module in my example project vs. yours. Notice you need to add your other 'pages' in the declaration. Try that and it may resolve it. I think that, as the error is indicating, the problem is with your module structure. I've run into something slightly similar in the past. Try changing how your components are declared in your modules and that should resolve it. Have to head out but I will check back later.

Comment: I don't think that did it either. Adding Tab1 and the rest of the pages to my declarations and entryComponents in the app.module didn't change anything, and even changing tab1's component declaration name to 'Home Page' didn't do much either. Thank you for your patience. @Muirik

Comment: But with my project example you can see that when the module structure is correct, you don't get that `*ngFor` error. You'll need to do more than just add the declarations, because right now each of your pages also have their own modules. I'm suggest you restructure how your modules are set up - because that error is telling you the problem lies there. It's hard to be more specific in stackblitz because of some of the extra libraries you're bringing in. I would start simple, get your components/modules working without errors and with a simple `*ngFor` - like my example - and go from there.

Comment: I would go step by step, testing each step of the way so that if/when an error does arise, it's much easier to reason about what change/addition likely led to the error.